# Configuring the Mesos Attribute to the slaves using the Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, mesos, dcos

I'm using the default AWS cloud formation script that is provided by the DCOS,trying to assign the mesos_attributes to the slaves using the following
(appended the following at the end of the Userdata)

```
                         "  \"path\": |-",
                            "\n",
                            "    /var/lib/dcos/mesos-slave-common",
                            "\n",
                            "- \"content\": \"MESOS_ATTRIBUTES=TYPE:XYZ;",
                            "\n"
```

The Server is started properly but the Stack never changes its state to completed from 'inprogress'.
I'm pretty sure that i'm making some mistake, can Someone throw more light on how to set the Mesos_attributes using the aws cloud formation

Comment: Can you see the user data script run logs? You may get hint there.

Comment: Can you see the user data script run logs? You may get hint there.

Comment: Thanks @ExploringApple , it worked. I Could fix the error